# What causes plaintext "The resource you are looking for has been removed" on ASP.NET MVC / IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, error-handling, iis-8

I have my ASP.NET MVC web app run on two different hosts, on one I get my custom 404 error with my nice text, but on the other I get plaintext

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I cannot find out what is causing this. The web.config is pretty much the same in all important aspects. What am I missing? Why is it behaving differently on two different hosts?

In web.config I have

```
<customErrors mode="Off">
<equal binding="HttpStatusCode" value="404" type="Int32" />
```

(not sure why I even have the equal bidining...) and everything is driven through code through return HttpNotFound ActionResult and default fallback route.

More specifically, the code that triggers this the plaintext on one host (and not on the other) is inside controller

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    // Some conditions...
    filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
}
```

which is then caught in

```
    protected void Application_EndRequest()
    {

        if (Context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
        {
            Response.ClearContent();

            var routeData = new RouteData();

            routeData.Values["controller"] = "Error";
            routeData.Values["action"] = "NotFound";

            Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

            var errorController = (IController)_unityContainer.Resolve<ErrorController>();

            errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
        }
```

IIS version is 8.5 on Windows Server 2012. Any pointers pls?